# How can I determine my Galaxy Nexus model variant?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have a Galaxy Nexus phone I want to root.

[Manual](http://galaxynexusroot.com/galaxy-nexus-root/how-to-root-galaxy-nexus-universal-guidegsmverizonsprintwindowslinuxmac/) differs between Verizon, Sprint and GSM subtypes.

Where can I check this subtype?