# What is yakju, gn, yakjuxw, takju etc?

Tags: device-firmware

I'm in the market of buying a Nexus 7, and these are what I understand some kind of firmware/maker identification. Can someone please explain all the different names?

Google sadly wasn't much help for me today.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28226/how-can-i-determine-my-galaxy-nexus-model-variant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Galaxy Nexus these are different builds:

- takju: devices sold through the Play Store in the US. Contains the Google Wallet aplication.
- yakju: devices sold through Google outside the US.
- yakjuxw: devices sold by Samsung.

If you buy yakjuxw I would recommend that you update to yakju with [factory images provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).

This way you will get the updates in time.

I wasn't aware that there are similar builds for the Nexus 7.

Comment: Just it case it was a typo, it yakju and not jakju.


Also, yakju images are almost the same as takju images except the absence of the Google Wallet app preinstalled.

yakjuxw is one of the images maintained by Samsung. There are other variants like yakjuux. Since these are not directly maintained by Google, the updates might take a bit longer to become available.


It is possible to flash a yakju factory image on the GSM/HSPA+ Galaxy Nexus to to have the updates directly from Google, but doing so will wipe the internal memory if the phone is not unlocked.

Comment: Realized that *gn* and *gnex* must be abbreviations for Galaxy Nexus. [*Nakasi* and *nakasig*](http://www.randomphantasmagoria.com/firmware/nexus-7/) seems to be stock Android firmwares. But what are the differences between them and *takju*/*yakju*?

Answer (score 4):

It's device internal codenames.

Reasons:

1. Device specifications is secret before release. After release, firmware not renamed, to exclude misunderstanding for developers.
2. One device may have different firmware versions, depends on target market and hardware configuration (modem, NFC, Wi-Fi settings).

Comment: In parts right: it's also different firmware versions. (Reason: Verizon subsidized wanted its own with locked bootloaders, another one comes preinstalled with *Google wallet*, the other without). See the factory images here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Comment: 2nd variant include not only vendor lock, but for example internation version may allow to use more Wi-Fi channels, at Russia needed to have Glonass support for pay smaller duty, there available LTE and 3G versions...

Answer (score 1):

This is an exert from  A Guide to Manually Install Android 4.2 Takju on Non-Yakju Galaxy Nexus written 14th Nov. 2012 available at:
http://webtrickz.com/guide-to-manually-install-android-4-2-takju-on-non-yakju-galaxy-nexus/

Following the availability of Nexus 4 and Nexus 10, Google has begun the rollout of Android 4.2 Jelly Bean OTA update for Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7 as well. Android 4.2 is currently available only for Takju variant of GSM/HSPA+ Galaxy Nexus and luckily Google has also released the Android 4.2 factory image for Takju Galaxy Nexus. Apparently, Non-Yakju Galaxy Nexus users wont receive this new update anytime soon as their phone is updated by Samsung whereas Yakju & Takju firmware are updated directly by Google.

However, users with adequate technical know-how can easily convert their non-yakju (yakjuxw, yakjuux, yakjusc, yakjuzs, yakjudv, yakjukr and yakjujp) device to Takju to receive prompt future OTA updates from Google.

Install Yakju or Takju? Takju, the firmware that ships with Google Play Store version of Galaxy Nexus (in US) apparently receives updates faster than the Yakju variant. So, it’s better to choose Takju over Yakju.

Comment: The content of that link doesn't really seem to explain what any of the terms (takju, yakju, etc) mean, though.

Comment: It doesnt explain their "literal translated meaning", but it does explain that they are firmware: That Yakju & Takju are firmware updated by Google, and that Non-Yakju firmware is updated by Samsung. It also tells you which receives updates faster and how if need be to take advantage of this. The literal, translated meaning of these words is in essence - meaningless. But what they are and how to benefit from them is meaningful. As the article (given by link) explains

Comment: I don't mean the literal translated meaning of the words. The article does very briefly mention that takju/yakju are updated by Google, but then it goes into instructions related to flashing different firmware without really explaining anything about what the yakjuxw/yakjuux/etc variants are, where they're sold, how they differ from takju (or plain ol' yakju), and so forth, at least as far as I see. That seemed like the crux of the OP's question to me, but it's kind of glossed over a bit is all.

Comment: I take your point, in the initial question it is not clear why the person asking the question wants exactly to know about the names ie what is the actual benefit of knowing, except for the above explanations given