# Why I do not receive Android updates for Samsung Galaxy Nexus GT i9250m?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, ota-update

I have **Galaxy Nexus GT-i9250m**. It is currently running **Android v4.1.1**. I am in **India**. I want to know how to update my phone to **v4.2 officially without rooting**. I have already tried checking for updates using `Settings->About phone-> System Updates`.

Asked similar question in [gsmarena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_nexus_i9250m-4432.php) but to no success. Tried solution provided there to Goto Settings-> Apps-> All-> Google services and Frameworks -> Clear Data, but to no success.

Is there any way doing it manually on Galaxy Nexus i9250m without rooting the phone? Like downloading the ROM and trying to run it.

Answer (score 5):

The devices which were bought from Google Play are takju and the ones from Samsung are akju. I think your phone is yakju (Google Play didn't sell  Devices in India).

Takju gets all updates directly from Google. If you want to get all updates from Google at the time of release you have to convert to takju.

### ***How Can you do that***

Please follow below to convert from yakju to takju (stock) without losing your data/apps: (assuming you know adb & fastboot and have set them up on your computer. Also assuming that bootloader is unlocked) [**Please read before you implement**]

1. Download [the 4.2 factory images for Takju](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#takju)
2. Extract files using 7-zip on Windows (you need to extract twice and will get the files as: bootloader-xxx.img; radio-xxx.img and image-xxx.zip)
3. Copy these files to the location android-sdk/platform-tools/ (if you have the android-sdk installed or to the location where adb & fastboot is)
4. Plug in your Galaxy Nexus (ensure Debug option is enabled under Developer Settings
5. Follow these commands:
   a. `adb reboot bootloader`
   b. `fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-xxx.img`
   c. `fastboot reboot-bootloader`
   d. `fastboot flash radio radio-xxx.img`
   e. `fastboot reboot-bootloader`
   f. `fastboot update image-xxx.zip`

This would update your Galaxy Nexus from Stock 4.1.2 (yakju) to Stock 4.2 (takju) without losing any data/apps

Note:

1. If you are using Windows, follow [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc4z-KYypgY) to setup adb and fastboot
2. If you are on Mac, use `./` before the commands for execution

**Note 2: With this method you don't need to remove the userdata.img as the command `fastboot update image-xxx.zip` does not touch the userdata on your device.**

*Disclaimer: Tried with Unlocked Bootloader, but you follow these at your own risk.

**Or you can Download factory image for yakju from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#yakjujdq39) and try similar step above for just updating (without converting from Yakju to takju)**

Comment: Does this method require rooting? I have currently 4.1.1 installed, is it advisable to directly install 4.2.2

Comment: Pls also tell, if something is messed up, how will I be able to recover to previous state.

Comment: your bootloader unlocked?

Comment: how to check this?

Comment: When you reboot the phone, you will see a little open lock symbol underneath the Google logo. That means you have an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: no, it do not show any logo underneath the Google logo, so I should first unlock bootloader

Comment: ys. But important thing is just backup before unlocking. It will wipe data.

Comment: So, as I can understand it will require rooting

Comment: I just checked, android variant is yakjuux.

Comment: Nope..For ulocking bootloader you dont need to be rooted

Comment: Use carbon app for backing up. It will not need to be rooted..https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en

Comment: or use this to backup->http://lifehacker.com/5976036/simple-adb-backup-backs-up-your-android-phone-from-the-desktop-no-root-required

Comment: As part of this answer relies on knowing the variant of Galaxy Nexus that you have, see also this question: [What is yakju, gn, yakjuxw, takju etc?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34358)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that India has not yet received this update yet. If that's the case, then you need to update it manually. This would require root access.

Here's a [manual update guide](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/413678/20121211/install-android421-jellybean-ota-galaxynexus-i9250-kalo.htm), in case you decide not to wait for an OTA update, which may never come.

**Edit #1:** If India already has it, and your phone cannot detect it, try this: Go to `Settings > Apps > ALL". Look for Google Services Framework, and click Force Stop button and Clear data button.

Comment: Any official source. Look at the link http://www.gsmarena.com/newscomm-5074.php. Many people in India have got 4.2 updates

Comment: @shubhansh: See my Edit #1

Comment: tried, but still not able to get update... :(

Comment: @shubhansh How about about if you Force Stop, Clear, RESTART, Check update?

Comment: @shubhansh Try to do it 2-3 times also. It might work.

Comment: @shubhansh Any updates from you? Did it work?

Comment: No, it did not worked. I tried around 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

OTA updates are country specific. In India 4.2 is not officially available for I9250. You can wait for official OTA or install manually as @geffchang suggested.

Comment: Any official source? http://www.gsmarena.com/newscomm-5074.php shows users in India getting 4.2 updates

Answer (score 0):

Try `adb sideload` from this [tutorial](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/12/android-4-2-update-jo40c-rolling-out-to-takju-galaxy-nexus-grab-the-manual-update-now/). Then use sideload again to update from 4.2 to 4.2.2 (it is much faster). You don't need root or flash bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Official OTA updates 4.2.1 are started for I9250 in India. I received it on 20-Mar-2013. Check for updates from your system settings.